# What method should I use if need to check for special characters and digits in name field or for special characters and alphanumeric in phone field?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, character, special-characters

I am trying to write a java code in selenium webdriver to print some error message on console if it finds some special or alphanumeric characters in phone field, and to print error message if it finds special characters in first name or last name field, I am not getting any method to check for special characters. Please help with some method.

Comment: Google for a regular expression

Comment: @deHaar nice reply, yes i have googled first, when i was unable to find any satisfactory reply there then only I thought to ask here.

Comment: Well, it's good you googled first, but you seem to haven't googled the right way because there are loads of tutorials, examples and so… First hit: [Regular expression for phone numbers](https://regexr.com/3c53v), second hit [a question from here (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 0):

I believe [java.lang.String.contains(CharSequence s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) 
is what you should use.